# sed remove lines with any alphabetical order

Tags: sed, text-parsing

im trying to remove all lines that have any 3 characters in alphabetical order with sed is there an easy way to do this instead of a bunch of pattern lines

```
sed -i '/abc/d 
       /bcd/d
       ....
      /xyz/d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With your attempted code, please try following `awk` code, where we are not writing all combinations of continuous alphabets. IMHO `awk` will be much efficient then `sed` here.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=""
  num=split("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z",arr1,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){ letters[arr1[i]]=i }
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(($i in letters) && ($(i+1) in letters) && ($(i+2) in letters)\
    && (letters[$i]+1==letters[$(i+1)]) && (letters[$i]+2==letters[$(i+2)])\
    && (letters[$(i+1)]+1==letters[$(i+2)])){
       print $i $(i+1) $(i+2)
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple and detailed explanation for whole `awk` program would be:

***Explanation of `BEGIN` block of `awk` program:***

- Creating field separator(`FS`) as NULL for all lines in `awk` so that each character could be compared to find out 3 consecutive occurrences of letters.
- Then using `split` function of `awk` creating an array named `arr1` where splitting all alphabets(small letters) into it with delimiter of `,` here.
- Then starting a `for` loop till value of `num`(could be written as 26 also since number of alphabets are always fixed), where creating an array named `letters` which has index as alphabets and its value will be their place value(their number on which they occur, eg: for `a` it will be `1`).

***Explanation of main block of `awk` program:***

- Running a `for` loop from 1st field to till `NF` all fields of current line basically.
- Then checking conditions there(basically checking if current field and next 2 fields are coming in letters array or not AND checking if their sequence is continuous or not).
- If all conditions mentioned are met then printing current and next 2 fields(which will basically print 3 letters).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '1{x;s/^/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/;x};G;/(...).*\n.*\1/!P' file
```

On the first line, introduce a literal alphabet in the hold space.

On each line, append the alphabet and using a three character back reference, compare it the the alphabet.

If there is a match, delete the line, otherwise, print the first line only.

N.B. The use of the `-n` turns off implicit printing and thus only when a match fails is the line printed.